# Python join parts of a string list together

Tags: python

I have a list of characters in python and I want to connect some of them while still maintaining a list.

I managed to detect which of those are letters A-Z\a-z and I only want to connect letters into whole words.

Example:

```
# List: ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', '=', ' ', 'H', 'E', 'Y']
# Wanted Result: ['HELLO', ' ', '=', ' ', 'HEY']
```

I want to be able to connect the letters but not the other symbols within the list while still maintaining a list as I showed in the example.

Appreciating all help :)

**EDIT**:

My failed attempt: (Note that when I copied it here it kinda messed up the tab order of things but overall that's the code I tried)

```
streak = False
marks = []
for i in range(len(lexes) - 1):
    if lexes[i] == "LETTER" and lexes[i + 1] == "LETTER" and not streak:
        marks.append(i)
        streak = True
    elif lexes[i] == "LETTER" and lexes[i + 1] != "LETTER" and streak:
        marks.append(i)
        streak = False
if len(marks) % 2 == 1:
    marks.append(len(lexes) - 1)
for i in range(len(marks)):
    newString = ""
    if i % 2 == 0:
        newString = "".join(words[marks[i]: marks[i + 1] + 1])
    for j in range(len(newString)):
        print(marks[i], ">>>", lexes[i])
        lexes.pop(marks[i])
        words.pop(marks[i])
    words.insert(marks[i], newString)
    lexes.insert(marks[i], "STRING")
    marks = np.subtract(marks, marks[i])
        # words.insert(marks[i], newString)
```

Result: From `['p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', "'", 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', "'", ')']`

To: `["print('Heel", 'l', '', 'd', "'", ')']`

Comment: Hi, can you give us an example of what you tried?

Comment: Alright, I'll edit the message, but it's long, not efficient and didn't work properly

**EDIT**: Done :)

Comment: btw what is `lexes` in the code you just posted?

Comment: I am making a lexer, basically lexes is another list of the lexed data of the words list, it lexes letters as LETTER and I want to turn a bunch of letters in a row into a STRING

And yes, the lexer works correctly, I checked a couple of times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to try:

```py
def join_letters(seq):
    '''
    >>> join_letters(['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', '=', ' ', 'H', 'E', 'Y'])
    ['HELLO', ' ', '=', ' ', 'HEY']
    '''
    ret = []
    for c in seq:
        if ret and ret[-1].isalpha() and c.isalpha():
            ret[-1] = ret[-1] + c

        else:
            ret.append(c)

    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)

    print(
        join_letters([
            'p', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', "'", 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ',
            'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', "'", ')'
        ]))
```

Comment: I will try it. But I didn't quite get it, I've never really seen the "isalpha()" method and I have no idea what it does. Could you please explain this to me? **EDIT** wait.. isalpha means like is an alphabetic?

Comment: Oh wow, this solution works perfectly! Thanks a lot :))

I am yet  to know what isalpha doing but I will look into it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for the task:

```
lst = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', '=', ' ', 'H', 'E', 'Y']

from itertools import groupby, count

out = [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, lambda k, c=count(1): 0 if 'A' <= k.upper() <= 'Z' else next(c))]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['HELLO', ' ', '=', ' ', 'HEY']
```

Comment: Interesting use of `groupby` I didn't see before (I liked the trick with `count`!)

Comment: although I believe it can be simplified to `0 if k.isalpha()` no?

Comment: I've never really tried the isalpha().. what does it do?

Comment: Only downside to the isAlpha is that it won't solve my lexing problem... while my loop would... well it shortens the entire thing and it works perfectly so I don't complain, I'll find a solution for the lexing, thanks a lot :) **EDIT**: Nvm I figured it out, just had to join the letters before lexing